# Ignoring everything other than integers scanf

Tags: c

I would like to take an array of integers as an input . Even if some one enter a space or an alpahabet, I want to ignore it.

```
int i=0;
while(L--){
    scanf("%d",&arr[i++]);
}
```

But if I enter: **4 wtf** the `arr[0]` gets initialized to 4 and the loop ends. Is there a way I can ignore everything after a space in `scanf` and just take the integers. 
The input can be of form: **4 abc 3 def 7 ghi**.

Comment: Use `fgets()` and `strtol()`.

Comment: Do you wanto take by single digit or you want the whole integer?

Comment: @Tahlil the whole integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think like this?

```
int a;
scanf("%d %*s", &a);
printf("%d\n",a);
```

And

```
input: 11 wwwww

output: 11
```

The `*` is used to skip an input without putting it in any variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets` to get the input string from `stdin` and then use `sscanf` to filter out integer from input string.

```
char input[50];
int num;
fgets(input, 50, stdin);

sscanf(input, "%d %*s", &num);
```

The `%*s` rejects the string after the integer encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while(L--){
    scanf("%d",&arr[i++]);
    while(getchar() != '\n'); // Consumes all characters after space.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you'd actually like to achieve here is to extract all numbers from a random input. I propose to use `fgets` to read the input into a buffer and next, using `isdigit` and `strtol`, extract the numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[255] = {0};
    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin); // read data from stdin
    char *ptr = buff;

    do {
        if(!isdigit(*ptr)) // check if current character is a digit 
            continue; // if not...
        long val = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10); // read a number
        printf("%ld\n", val); // print it   
    } while(*ptr++); // ...move to next character
}
```

...and the quick test:

```
[root@dmudms01 temp]# ./a.out 
1abc23 **4
1
23
4
```