# Read only numbers from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I seen Q&A like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588058/read-two-variables-in-a-single-line-with-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336943/removing-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string) but I still have a problem.

What I want is to get a string that might contain non-digits characters, and I want to only extract 2 numbers from that string. So, if my string is `12 ds  d21a` I want to extract `['12', '21']`.

I tried using:

```
import re
non_decimal = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')
non_decimal.sub("",input())
```

and fed this string `12 123124kjsv dsaf31rn`. The result was `12123124` which is nice, but I want the non-digit characters to separate the numbers.

Next I tried to add `split` - `non_decimal.sub("",input().split())`. Didn't help.

How can I do that (assuming there is way that does not include scanning the whole string, iterating over it and extracting the digits "manually")?

For more clarification, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22984026/3512538) is what I want to achieve, in C.

Comment: `input_ = '12 123124kjsv dsaf31rn'
non_decimal = re.findall(r'[\d.]+', input_)`
Does that do the trick?

Comment: thanks @ClsForCookies! Updated ans!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `re.findall()` method in this case -

```
input_ = '12 123124kjsv dsaf31rn' 
non_decimal = re.findall(r'[\d.]+', input_)
```

Output -

```
['12', '123124', '31']
```

Answer (score 2):

@Vivek answer will solve your issue.

Here is another approach , Just an opinion :

```
import re
pattern=r'[0-9]+'
string_1="""12 ds  d21a
12 123124kjsv dsaf31rn"""

match=re.finditer(pattern,string_1)
print([find.group() for find in match])
```

output:

```
['12', '21', '12', '123124', '31']
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to extract are positive integers, do this :

```
>>> string = "h3110 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog"
>>> [int(x) for x in string.split() if x.isdigit()]
[23, 11, 2]
```

Then if you want more conditions and want to include scientific notations too:

```
import re

# Format is [(<string>, <expected output>), ...]
ss = [("apple-12.34 ba33na fanc-14.23e-2yapple+45e5+67.56E+3",
       ['-12.34', '33', '-14.23e-2', '+45e5', '+67.56E+3']),
      ('hello X42 I\'m a Y-32.35 string Z30',
       ['42', '-32.35', '30']),
      ('he33llo 42 I\'m a 32 string -30', 
       ['33', '42', '32', '-30']),
      ('h3110 23 cat 444.4 rabbit 11 2 dog', 
       ['3110', '23', '444.4', '11', '2']),
      ('hello 12 hi 89', 
       ['12', '89']),
      ('4', 
       ['4']),
      ('I like 74,600 commas not,500', 
       ['74,600', '500']),
      ('I like bad math 1+2=.001', 
       ['1', '+2', '.001'])]

for s, r in ss:
    rr = re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?", s)
    if rr == r:
        print('GOOD')
    else:
        print('WRONG', rr, 'should be', r)
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string).